# How to get max or avg from Bucket Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

How can I get avg or max doc_count from my buckets.

There are many examples of how to do it with numeric fields, 
but I need to get nax count of distinct devices.

My query:

```
POST sessions/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    ...
  },
  "aggs": {
    "1": {
      "terms": {
        "size" : 10,
        "order" : {
            "_count" : "desc"
        },
        "field": "deviceId"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example Result:

```
  "aggregations": {
      "1": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 62,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 326057,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "878f6sdb0245e3d8bd",
               "doc_count": 230
            },
            {
               "key": "ee43b17fsfc00fd04f",
               "doc_count": 224
            },
            {
               "key": "bdcdeb0eeaffcfe748",
               "doc_count": 141
            },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`Terms aggregation` by default sorts the bucket in the decreasing order of `doc_count`. So If you fetch first bucket, that will be the one with maximum doc_count.

Query:

```
POST sessions/_search
{
 "size": 0,
 "query": {
 ...
},
"aggs": {
"1": {
  "terms": {
    "size" : 1,
    "order" : {
        "_count" : "desc"
    },
    "field": "deviceId"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I don't think finding average is possible using one query.But you can use  below queries to get the result

`Sum Of All doc counts = Total documents` in your index.

First find total documents using

```
GET /order/order/_count
```

Then find buckets count using `cardinality`

```
{
"aggs" : {
    "device_count" : {
        "cardinality" : {
            "field" : "deviceId"
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

Then divide both the results to get the average.

- PLease note that counts returned by `cardinality` are approximate. Refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html for more details.
  Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok That make sense, but what about AVG?

Comment: @gdevereg Do you want to get average doc_count which means (sum_of_all_doc_count/number_of_buckets)?.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I'm looking for.